VS Code breaks after adding sudo when using pyautogui
Added this line of code:
pyautogui.typewrite('sudo the/address.sh')

Then VS Code broke, and even in a different Python file a simple "hello world" wouldn't even work.
It would only work after removing the sudo thing, then restarting VS Code.
I tried restarting miniconda, creating a new conda environment, but to no avail.

sudo will always prompt for a password,
In most cases the prompt would be invisible, where you just type your password and press enter without seeing what characters you've actually typed.
Due to the fact that you've added no screenshots and no code, im assuming that:
VSCode is prompting you for a password
I have no idea of the way you are running your program, however if you are running it from the terminal, Try entering your root password and pressing enter
Good luck!

Thanks, Is there any alternative to press enter as I get same error when. I use pyautogui press enter
